# Is the Born rule a red herring in explaining the measurement problem?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurement-problem, wavefunction-collapse, born-rule

Many explanations of the measurement problem try to derive the Born rule from Schrodinger evolution, for example Many worlds. I have two reasons to think the Born rule isn't fundamentally related to the measurement problem:

1.The Born rule appears in Koopman Von Neumann mechanics : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koopman%E2%80%93von_Neumann_classical_mechanics

2.Born rule also doesn't appear in phase space quantum mechanics, which directly deals with probabilities instead of probability amplitudes. This makes me think that probabilities are built into the theory right from the beginning. Trying to derive the probabilities from the Shcrodinger equation would be like a dog chasing its tail.

Since KvN is classical, I think the Born rule has more to do with hilbert space formulations of mechanics, be it quantum of classical. The measurement problem is a physical problem, which is independent of the way we express the theory.

**Please tell me why the Born rule is fundamentally related to the measurement problem.**

Comment: Downvoting without giving reason. A reason text box should appear after pressing downvote.

Comment: Probably downvoted as you are not asking a question but stating a personal theory.  That's off-topic here.  We're a Q&A site for mainstream physics not a discussion site.  Voting is deliberately anonymous and requires no reason and this is long-established policy.  You can ask about that policy on SE Meta or Physics SE Meta but please do a search first.

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine I don't get it. The question is "Is the Born rule fundamentally tied to the measurement problem or not?" I gave my reasons that it isn't. Only the reason was my "pesonal theory". The question is still there.

Comment: The post reads like a personal theory (also note that check-my-work type questions are off-topic so that's another potential issue).  I'd suggest rephrasing it to emphasize it's a question (in the body !).  Posts that boil down to "am I right" tend to get easily labelled as check-my-work or personal-theories.  Note that the subject line is not always a good place to put a question.  Best options are first or last in a post IMO.

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine I rephrased

Comment: This is confusing.  The measurement problem is distinct from  the probabilistic nature of QM or the Born rule (which is just a way of computing probabilities).

Comment: Deformation quantization is ***completely*** equivalent to the Hilbert space formulation and does compute expectation values like it, by tracing them with the analog of the density matrix. Perhaps you should *detail and clarify* what you mean by your point 2, which, as things stand, is completely oracular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's true that the Born rule and measurement problem are not that closely intertwined. Deriving the Born rule is nevertheless important for a couple of reasons.

One is that it is fundamental to theories trying to explain how quantum mechanics arises from more basic mechanisms. The Copenhagen Interpretation simply asserts the Born rule as an 'axiom' without explanation of how or why - treating the underlying mechanism as a theoretical 'black box'. The wavefunction collapses (how?) on being observed (how is that defined?), jumping instantaneously (how does that fit with relativity?) to an eigenstate (why eigenstates?) randomly selected (so non-deterministic?) with a probability equal to the complex amplitude times its conjugate (what do the complex numbers mean, physically? why this value? How does it work?). There are many questions the Born rule leaves unanswered. The measurement problem is only one of them.

Attempts to explain quantum mechanics in terms of a better, deeper, more fundamental theory need to provide improved explanations of the observations we know. The Born rule is a mystery central to quantum mechanics. We cannot claim to have explained quantum mechanics without addressing it. And any theory that can explain how it arises from more basic considerations would gain a lot of credibility as a candidate theory.

While you could explain the Born rule without answering the question of the measurement problem, or vice versa, a theory that only answered one of the mysteries would be necessarily incomplete, and less credible than one that answered both.

The other reason is that Everett claimed in his thesis to have provided an explanation of the Born rule, which critics found to be inadequate. It has provided a convenient reason to reject Everett's interpretation, and therefore advocates both for and against have focussed on it. It's probable that had Everett not mentioned it, it wouldn't be such a topic of debate.